# Accessing Own Project Class from Pods

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

How could I access my project from Pod Framework? I don't understand how to import my project into Pods target.
I would like to edit the Framework and use my Project class into it.

MyProject.xcworkspace allows me only to import Pods Framework and not vice versa.

So every time I try to access to a own class it show me this error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'HomeDetailVC'

Even though my class is marked with the `open` keyword.

Comment: The point of frameworks in the first place is that the code can be included in any project that imports them. Because of this, modifying a framework using code from the project that relies on the framework itself is a broken pattern. You should likely modify the framework itself to not depend on the project that imports it or manually include the framework's source code into your project and modify it that way assuming it isn't obfuscated with the understanding that it is now no longer really a reusable framework just included code from another project and inherently not reusable any longer.

Comment: This is the only (best) way to do it?

Comment: If you plan on continuing to use Cocoapods, it's really your only option. Unless your plan is to create a new framework using all the amalgamated code, your framework cannot depend on code from the importing project. It's not really a framework at that point and, as far as I can tell, it's a broken pattern.

Comment: Could you make it as answer? So I can accept it. Thank

Comment: Anyway, how to access my Swift class from the Pod that's the question! :)